# Java assert printing

Tags: java, eclipse, assert

I need to print the statement in the assertion to the console when condition is true in eclipse.
How?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        assert(args[0].equals("x")): "kate";
    } catch(Error e) {
        System.out.print("ae ");
    } finally {
        try {
             assert(args[0].equals("y")): "jane";
        } catch(Exception e2) {
             System.out.print("ae2 ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit ..when 2==2 is there in that case?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you please explain it more?

Comment: when <assert 2==2 : "We have a problem" > condition is true i need "We have a problem" get printed on the console in eclipse.

Comment: @sonia Show us your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to:

- Select **Run** → **Run Configuration** → Right click on **Java Application** → **New** → Go to **Arguments** tab → Write **-ea** in *VM* arguments:

[image]

Now, when you have something like:

`assert(1==2) : "Error!!!";`

You'll see in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Error!!!
    at .....
```

Comment: I added VM arguments, still i am unable to see the assertions error in my console log.